# How safe is to use setTimeout this way in production?

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

In order to cope with the fact that Mongo does not support atomic multidocuments transactions I am trying to implement profile deletion in this way:

1. When a user asks to delete its profile, I remove the User document from Mongo and tell the user the profile is deleted;
2. I call the function below to delete all its posts (after sending a response to the user)

In order to be sure all the posts are (eventually) deleted - despite errors - I use a setTimeout as follows:

```
    var removePosts =function(authorId,cb){
        var remove= function(){
           Post.find({'author':authorId}).remove(function(err){
            if(err){
                  logger.error(err);   
                  setTimeout(remove,25000);
            }else{
               cb();
            }
           });
        };      
        remove();
    };
```

In development it seems to work. But how safe is it in production? Is there any WTF I should expect? 
Thanks!

Comment: Seems fine! It could of course loop forever if an error arises, but given the duration of the timeout that shouldn't really cause any issues with crashing or something like that. However, there must be another way to do this, but I don't know MongoDB good enough to come up with anything.